# Lag on dual scroll with margin top

Tags: jquery, scroll, multiple-columns

I have a problem with a jquery function I've made for a website that have 2 different height columns and should scroll together at different speeds.

Here you can find the fiddle : 
http://jsfiddle.net/w4g3rvhh/

```
var maxscroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
var projHeight = $("#projects").outerHeight( true );
var agencHeight = $("#agency").outerHeight( true );
var diffheight = projHeight - agencHeight;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var margin = window.pageYOffset * diffheight / maxscroll;
  $("#agency").css("margin-top", margin + "px");
});
```

It works kinda great for me, but multiple user have a "laggy" behavior. The left side kinda jump weirdly.

I find out that the wrong behavior appears on mac safari ( sometimes chrome )

EDIT : I've made a video of the encountered behavior if needed : https://youtu.be/afKziooQLac

Comment: For me, on chrome it isn't moving at all and the scroll is reallly slow. On firefox it does a laggy movement up and down

Comment: Well for me it works perfect in FF v 56.0.1 (64-bit) and Chrome Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit) but Microsoft Edge is choppy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use the +,  and not the -

```
var maxscroll = $(document).height() - $(window).height();
var projHeight = $("#projects").outerHeight( true );
var agencHeight = $("#agency").outerHeight( true );
var diffheight = projHeight + agencHeight;
$(window).scroll(function () {
  var margin = window.pageYOffset * diffheight / maxscroll;
  $("#agency").css("margin-top", margin + "px");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

On older devices this can be caused because of the frequency that the scroll event is triggered when scrolling. It triggers many times sequentially, and thus the calculation is done multiple times per second. Old devices can't keep up which causes lag. Normally, [throttling](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/) is the proposed solution, but to mimic a 'sticky' effect or parallel scrolling that doesn't work neatly of course -- however, see [discussion in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46490086/lag-on-dual-scroll-with-margin-top/46490349#comments-46490349). Try by putting as much of the calculation outside of the scroll handler, e.g.:

```
var win = $(window),
    maxscroll = $(document).height() - win.height(),
    agency = $("#agency"),
    h = ($("#projects").outerHeight(true) - agency.outerHeight(true)) / maxscroll;

win.scroll(function() {
  agency.css("margin-top", win.scrollTop() * h + "px");
});
```

Comment: Wouldn't throttling still be smooth enough to look good? For ex using requestAnimationFrame?

Comment: @arbuthnott Perhaps. But I guess you would have to benchmark all browsers and see how many times per second the scroll event is toggled, and then use an interval in your throttling that is less than that but that is still smooth. I do not have the time to test it, but indeed - in an enterprise environment that's how you would test it and see what's best.

Comment: I've made a video of the encountered behavior if needed : https://youtu.be/afKziooQLac

Comment: @Leeroy521 Firefox handles scroll different than Chrome. It is likely that Firefox fires less/more events resulting in this behavior. I have no fix for this.